# The limit as x approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

For some reason I can't solve this.

$$ \lim_{x \to \pm \infty}\left(\cos\left(e^{x^{1/3}+\sin x}\right)\right) $$

Comment: Hello! Nice question. I have edited the formatting. It's nice to use $\LaTeX$. Also, in future, please make an attempt to show us what you have tried before asking for direct help.

Comment: Sure I'll do that. It's just that I don't know where to start...

Comment: That's perfectly fine. That happens to me all the time! But at least give us a background of what you know or what you might think could be a start, even if it's wrong. That's why we are here to help. 

StackExhange asks that you show us that you are actually thinking about the problem before seeking help. 

Welcome to Math.SE!

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll keep that in mind now... It would help I if I could get a tutorial as to how to properly format my question so that the readability is easier... I'll learn as time passes by

Comment: [Here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:About) is an excellent guide on $\LaTeX$ usage. You should learn $\LaTeX$. It is very helpful not only for posting on forums but for submitting homework in high school and college and make it look impressive. I learned all my $\LaTeX$ from the guide I have linked you to.

Comment: Thanks for the guide. Have an awesome day!

Comment: Thanks. You too! Also, would you mind upvoting my comments, please? No need to, just a way of converting that "Thank you". :)

Comment: Edit! That's not the question! The format is wrong! its cos (e) and e has an exponent of (x^(1/3) + sinx)! Not just x^(1/3)

Comment: Ah! Your delimeters did not suggest that. I'll fix it right away. **Edit**: Done.

Comment: Oh man! Now I am confused again... Does the solution of the bottom still apply?

Comment: Yes, it does. I might post a full solution later. Also, please don't add extraneous comments in your OP. I've removed them.

Comment: Okay thats great!

Answer (score 3):

Because $\lim_{x\to \infty} x^{1/3}+ \sin x = \infty$, the argument of cosine goes to infinity; hence the limit does not exist.

Comment: So when writing this question I would move my limit inside the exponent of e and then take the limit of x^(1/3) + sinx and specify that the function does not converge? Also what about negative infinity as wolphram alpha specifies that the limit does exist but I don't know how to prove that....?

Comment: If you switch to $-\infty$, now the argument of the cosine goes to $0$ so your limit is 1.

Comment: How will I prove that?

Comment: Cosine and exponential are continuous functions, so you can pull the limit inside, as you suggested above.

Comment: Look at the part that is concerned with $x$, in this case $x^{1/3}+\sin x$. If you made $x$ larger and larger, where does $x^{1/3}$ go? And does $\sin x$ go anywhere outside $[-1,1]$ as $x$ increases? Then deduce where $\mathrm{e}^{x^{1/3}+\sin x}$ goes and subsequently what happens with the whole thing (does $\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos x$ exist?)

Comment: Okay I see what you mean... I'm going to attempt it now and apply the squeeze theorem on cos(x) and sin(x). Thanks.

Comment: I still don't see how you got −∞ when limit x approaches −∞ of the function leads to cos going to 0 thereby giving the answer as 1

Comment: Because $\lim_{x\to -\infty}e^x=0$.

Comment: But it's not $$ e^{x} $$ . It is $$ e^{x^{1/3}+sin(x)} $$

Answer (score 2):

This limit does not exists.

For,  $$ \lim_{x \to + \infty}\left(\cos\left(e^{x^{1/3}+\sin x}\right)\right) $$

$$ \left(\cos\left(e^\infty\right)\right) $$

which doesn't exist.

But for,
$$ \lim_{x \to -\infty}\left(\cos\left(e^{x^{1/3}+\sin x}\right)\right) $$
$$ \left(\cos\left(e^{-\infty}\right)\right) = cos(0) = 1$$
it exists.